# a href link for entire div in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is what I am trying to accomplish in HTML/CSS:

I have images in different heights and widths, but they are all under 180x235. So what I want to do is create a `div` with `border` and `vertical-align: middle` them all. I have successfully done that but now I am stuck on how to properly a href link the entire `div`.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="parentdivimage" style="position:relative;width:184px;height:235px;border-width:2px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;text-align:center;">
    <div id="childdivimage" style="position:absolute;top:50%;height:62px;margin-top:-31px;">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" height="62" width="180">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that for the sake of copy pasting here easily, the style code is inline.

I read somewhere that I can simply add another parent div on top of the code and then do a href inside that. However, based on some research it won't be valid code.

So to sum it up again, I need the entire div (`#parentdivimage`) to be a href link.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

> **UPDATE 06/10/2014:** using div's inside a's is semantically correct in HTML5.

You'll need to choose between the following scenarios:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <div>
        Hello world
    </div>
</a>
```

which is semantically incorrect, but it will work.

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='http://google.com';">
    Hello world
</div>
```

which is semantically correct but it involves using JS.

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <span style="display: block;">
        Hello world
    </span>
</a>
```

which is semantically correct and works as expected but is not a div any more.

Comment: lol :)
Visual Web Developer 2010 says: Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'div' cannot be nested within element 'a'.

Comment: Yep - an `<a>` tag is inline, and a `<div>` tag is block.  It's not valid to put a block level tag inside an inline tag, so that's the source of the error.

Comment: You could use a `span` instead of a `div` and use css's `display: block;` to make it look as desired and semantic.

Comment: You should just set the `display:block` on the `<a>` tag. It will become a block element without nesting.

Comment: HTML5 allows to nest `<div>` tags inside `<a>` tags.

Comment: I don't think semantics has anything to do with it. It's now valid and technically correct but has nothing to do with semantics.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy Source?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Check the second code example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: @jvannistelrooy I don't see any mention of allowing flow elements.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)." So, W3C mentions some examples of flow content, although they don't mention <div> tags explicitly.

Comment: Google uses first solution on its GMD page: https://material.io/components/sliders#continuous-sliders. Furthermore, `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div>
     anything
  </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>` is tested valid.

Comment: Better do not use or even recommend #2 with `onclick`, it has many issues.

Answer (score 43):

Why don't you strip out the `<div>` element and replace it with an `<a>` instead?  Just because the anchor tag isn't a div doesn't mean you can't style it with `display:block`, a height, width, background, border, etc.  You can make it *look* like a div but still *act* like a link.  Then you're not relying on invalid code or JavaScript that may not be enabled for some users.

Comment: interesting. can you please give an example so I can try out. Thanks

Comment: Good, but won't work great in the case where you have another `<a>` inside the `<div>`.

Comment: great solution - this works well for mobile Safari where you need anchor tags to avoid handling touches manually

Answer (score 17):

Do it like this:

Parentdivimage should have specified width and height, and its position should be:

```
position: relative;
```

Just inside the parentdivimage, next to other divs that parent contains you should put:

```
<a href="linkt.to.smthn.com"><span class="clickable"></span></a>
```

Then in css file:

```
.clickable {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;     
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The span tag will fill out its parent block which is parentdiv, because of height and width set to 100%. Span will be on the top of all of surrounding elements because of setting z-index higher than other elements. Finally span will be clickable, because it's inside of an 'a' tag.

Comment: aaamazing, after searching for days this is the solution that worked for me

Comment: I've found use for this over the accepted answer; all text within the "a block" becomes underlined. Yeah, you can get rid of the underlines via text-decoration but that property isn't inherited. Using your method, @denu, makes it simple.

Comment: Yes it is the solution Bootstrap uses with its stretched-link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/stretched-link/

Comment: @denu I saw your solution after I came up with my own version. Would be nice to get your thoughts! https://stackoverflow.com/a/67156294/1134080

Answer (score 4):

Going off of what Surreal Dreams said, it's probably best to style the anchor tag in my experience, but it really does depend on what you are doing.  Here's an example:

Html:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
.parent-div {
  width: 200px;
}
a {
  display:block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/zijijuduqo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

Two things you can do:

1. Change `#childdivimage` to a `span` element, and change `#parentdivimage` to an anchor tag.  This may require you to add some more styling to get things looking perfect.  *This is preffered, since it uses semantic markup, and does not rely on javascript.*
2. Use Javascript to bind a click event to `#parentdivimage`.  You must redirect the browser window by modifying `window.location` inside this event.  This is TheEasyWay<sup>TM</sup>, but will not degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm surprised no one suggested this simple trick so far! [(denu does something similar though.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908881/1134080)*

If you want a link to cover an entire `div`, an idea would be to create an empty `<a>` tag as the first child:

```html
<div class="covered-div">
  <a class="cover-link" href="/my-link"></a>
  <!-- other content as usual -->
</div>
```

```css
div.covered-div {
  position: relative;
}

a.cover-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This works especially great when using `<ul>` to create block sections or slideshows and you want the whole slide to be a link (instead of simply the text on the slide). In the case of an `<li>` it's not valid to wrap it with an `<a>` so you'd have to put the cover link inside the item and use CSS to expand it over the entire `<li>` block.

Do note that having it as the first child means it will make other links or buttons inside the text unreachable by clicks. If you want them to be clickable, then you'd have to make it the last child instead.

In the case of the original question:

```html
<div id="parentdivimage" style="position:relative;width:184px;height:235px;border-width:2px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;text-align:center;">
  <a class="cover-link" href="/my-link"></a> <!-- Insert this empty link here and use CSS to expand it over the entire div -->
  <div id="childdivimage" style="position:absolute;top:50%;height:62px;margin-top:-31px;">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" height="62" width="180">
  </div>
  <!-- OR: it can also be here if the childdivimage divs should have their own clickable links -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `div` of `id="childdivimag"` a `span` instead, and wrap that in an `a` element. As the `span` and `img` are in-line elements by default this remains valid, whereas a `div` is a block level element, and therefore invalid mark-up when contained within an `a`.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't work for me because i dont want the image to be a href. I want the entire block to a href link..converting the childdivimage to a span and wrapping it in an a doesn't accomplish what i want

Answer (score 2):

put `display:block` on the anchor element. and/or `zoom:1`;

but you should just really do this.

```
a#parentdivimage{position:relative; width:184px; height:235px; 
                 border:2px solid #000; text-align:center; 
                 background-image:url("myimage.jpg"); 
                 background-position: 50% 50%; 
                 background-repeat:no-repeat; display:block; 
                 text-indent:-9999px}
```

```
<a id="parentdivimage">whatever your alt attribute was</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many ways.
a. Using nested  inside a  tag.

```
<a href="link1.html">
   <div> Something in the div </div>
 </a>
```

b. Using the Inline JavaScript Method

```
<div onclick="javascript:window.location.href='link1.html' "> 
  Some Text 
</div>
```

c. Using jQuery inside  tag

HTML:

```
<div class="demo" > Some text here </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".demo").click( function() {
  window.location.href="link1.html";
 });
```

Comment: option "a" is NOT sematicaly correct, because it's not allowed to use block-elements (div, table, p, ...) as child of inline-elements (a, span, b, u, i, ...). The browser renders it, but it's not html-conform.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is put a span inside the `<a>` tag, set the span to block, and add size to the span, or just apply the styling to the `<a>` tag. Definitely handle the positioning in the `<a>` tag style. Add an `onclick event` to the `a where` JavaScript will catch the event, then return false at the end of the JavaScript event to prevent default action of the `href` and bubbling of the click. This works in cases with or without JavaScript enabled, and any AJAX can be handled in the Javascript listener.

If you're using jQuery, you can use this as your listener and omit the `onclick` in the `a` tag.

```
$('#idofdiv').live("click", function(e) {
    //add stuff here
    e.preventDefault; //or use return false
});
```

this allows you to attach listeners to any changed elements as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A link with `<div>` tags:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';">
     Something in the div 
</div>
```

A link with `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div>
        Something in the div 
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply do

```
onClick="location.href='url or path here'"
```

Comment: @ChrisClaude i didn't see any other answer exactly like this one.