# How To Add An "a href" Link To A "div"?

Tags: html, href, addition

I need to know how to add an a href link to a div? Do you put the a href tag arounf the entire "buttonOne" div? Or should it be around or inside the "linkedinB" div?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="buttonOne">
  <div id="linkedinB">
    <img src="img/linkedinB.png" width="40" height="40">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This post had some CSS some minutes ago and I created a http://jsfiddle.net/n3ckB/ of it. Enjoy!

Comment: There was a time when a tags were anchors on hypertext. Hence, divs had no anchors around them because they were no real content but content wrappers. Young boys skipped ye olde Interweb times... :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Can't you surround it with an a tag?

```
  <a href="#"><div id="buttonOne">
        <div id="linkedinB">
            <img src="img/linkedinB.png" width="40" height="40">
        </div>
  </div></a>
```

Comment: that generate problems in ie8, thats because is semantically incorrect

Comment: downed: because semantically incorrect. please refer to: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4465956/1343488) answer

Comment: In HTML5 using `<div>`inside an `<a>` is correct. Checkout the updated page linked by @zhirzh above.

Comment: In addition, it's almost impossible to style the `<div>` when it is surrounded by an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 6):

try to implement with javascript this:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="myhref('http://web.com');" >some stuff </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myhref(web){
      window.location.href = web;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it doesn't matter as there is no content between the two `div`s.

Either one will get the browser to scroll down to it.

The `a` element will look like:

```
<a href="mypageName.html#buttonOne">buttonOne</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="mypageName.html#linkedinB">linkedinB</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a class named `overlay` and apply the following css to it:

```
a.overlay { width: 100%; height:100%; position: absolute; }
```

Make sure it is placed in a positioned element.

Now simply place an `<a>` tag with that class inside the div you want to be linkable:

```
<div id="buttonOne">
  <a class="overlay" href="......."></a>
    <div id="linkedinB">
       <img src="img/linkedinB.png" alt="never forget the alt tag" width="40" height="40"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

PhilipK's suggestion might work but it won't validate because you can't place a block element (`div`) inside an inline element (`a`). And when your website doesn't validate the W3C Ninja's will come for you!

An other advice would be to try avoiding inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
 <a href="#"id="buttonOne">
            <div id="linkedinB">
                <img src="img/linkedinB.png" width="40" height="40">
            </div>
      </div>
```

However, it will still be a link. If you want to change your link into a button, you should rename the #buttonone to #buttonone a { your css here }.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions don't seem to be working for me, I have the following code. How to put link into the last two divs.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<style>
/* Import */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400);
* {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;  
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease; 
  -o-transition: all 0.025s ease; 
}

/* Colors */

#ora {
  background-color: #e67e22; 
}

#red {
  background-color: #e74c3c; 
}

#orab {
  background-color: white; 
  border: 5px solid #e67e22; 
}

#redb {
  background-color: white; 
  border: 5px solid #e74c3c; 
}
/* End of Colors */

.B {
  width: 240px; 
  height: 55px; 
  margin: auto; 
  line-height: 45px; 
  display: inline-block; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -o-box-sizing: border-box; 
} 

#orab:hover {
  background-color: #e67e22; 
}

#redb:hover {
  background-color: #e74c3c; 
}
#whib:hover {
  background-color: #ecf0f1; 
}

/* End of Border

.invert:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  -moz-filter: invert(1);
  -ms-filter: invert(1);
  -o-filter: invert(1);
}
</style>
<h1>Flat and Modern Buttons</h1>
<h2>Border Stylin'</h2> 

<div class="B bo" id="orab">See the movies list</div></a>
<div class="B bo" id="redb">Avail a free rental day</div>

</html>
```