# How can I use Href in div

Tags: html, validation, href

Can I use href in div? Because I have errors in validator! 
How can use hred in div? 
My code:

```html
<div data-href="#member_log" login="0" class="num_id bookmark" id="girl" girlId=""></div>
```

And error in validator: 
Attribute href not allowed on element div at this point.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have vip profiles on my web-site. 
http://prntscr.com/b2pied
And when you click on the "+" - Open the login window

Comment: Its not possible. If you require you can simply add a div inside an anchor tag and provide href attribute to it.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056901/how-to-add-an-a-href-link-to-a-div