# html link correct placement?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, href

normally for a html link:

```
<p><a href="#">this is link</a></p>
<h1><a href="#">this is link</a></h1>
<span><a href="#">this is link</a></span>
```

Can a href link wrap outside of other element like so?

```
<a href="#"><p>this is link</p></a>
<a href="#"><h1>this is link</h1></a>
<a href="#"><span>this is link</span></a>
```

and also outside a div?

```
<a href="#">
 <div>this is div
     <p>here is the paragraph</p>
     <div>and nested div</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Give it a try - does it work?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465923/a-href-link-for-entire-div-in-html-css

Comment: ya it works for me but I'm not sure doing so is will validate in the validator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There isn't any "prohibited" elements for `<a>` in the spec (except for the standard `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>`, `<title>`, `<meta>`...). `<a>` links, and everyone deserves to be linked.

Keep in mind tho that `<a>` is inline, so you will have to set `display: block` to use it like `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do this.  It looks a little odd, but it will work.  Take note that in your second example the text will all map to the same link "#".