# can ::before pseudo element be a link?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to add metadata to html, and show link from ::before {} element.

```html
<div>
    lorem
    <span data-discussion="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826249/html-link-correct-placement>
        ipsum
    </span>
<div>
```

```css
[data-discussion]:hover::before{
    background: pink;
    content: attr(data-discussion);
    /* link be here! */
}
```

The `::before` attribute is really convenient, as I am able to apply it to the whole page without rewriting my html.
Is there a way to add href-like link to it?

Comment: It’s not possible already this question posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible with just CSS, you would have to generate `a` tags , for example with JavaScript.

Comment: pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM and you can't bind any events directly to them, you can only bind to their parent elements.