# Linking a div without javascript?

Tags: html, href

It's a very simple question, you may say that i can do this:

```
<a href="link"><div></div></a>
```

but when i hover the div (110x74)px it hovers all across the width of the page, as if the div has a width of 100%, so when i click on blank part of the page it acts like if there's a link there, ideas? thanks

I also tried with javascript and it worked but many smartphones can't support it.

Comment: Read [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct), HTML 4.01 specifies that <a> elements may only contain inline elements. A <div> is a block element, so it may not appear inside an <a>.

Comment: put content in the div - style the div

Comment: @nick it is correct in HTML5

Comment: Just FYI, it can be done with `onclick` and remove the need for `a` tag.

Comment: I think This helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465923/a-href-link-for-entire-div-in-html-css

Comment: @Gil yeah but i don't want to use js because many devices do not support it

Comment: @Gil , it says in the title 'no javascript'...

Comment: @nick I have solved your problem. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @nick really? most mobile devices have more advanced browsers than stationary devices, due to consistent updates. The only reason today that a mobile device doesn't support js is because it was intentionally disabled, and that will cause practically almost all sites to work incorrectly (or not at all). If you have some restrictions you have to work by then it's another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know what you want exactly? [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52zwR/) shows a DIV with the given dimensions and it works as you require... you might want to elaborate some more on what it is you're looking for...

CSS:

```
.test{
    width: 110px;
    display: block;
}

.test div{
    height: 74px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href='#' class='test'><div></div></a>
```

Comment: yeah but look that if you hover the blank part next to the div it acts like a link

Comment: tried that, i solved the problem for the web version so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nNA7G/7/

HTML:

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com"><div><p>hi lol</p></div></a>
```

CSS:

```
a
{
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

div
{
    width: 80px;
    background-color: khaki;
}
```

Comment: still the same problem, i'm starting to think i'm the only one who have it

Comment: @nick Please tell me which browser and which version of that browser you're using.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you problem -since my english language is week-, I think if you set wrapper for link and set link as diplay: inline-block .. the width will be exactly, and you can increase width any time as block ..

use display block or inline-block will resolved width problem ...

good luck, and sorry if not that what you mean ..

Good luck mate ^^

Comment: gonna try that ,anyway, with that i have to search for another way to align it to the center with a smaller screen, since it's a responsive page