# How to make div a linkable button

Tags: html

I am new in html and i wanna ask how to put a link for the button

```
<div 
    class="tp-caption RotatingWords-Button rev-btn  rs-parallaxlevel-0"
    id="slide-333-layer-7"
    style="z-index: 11; white-space: nowrap;outline:none;box-shadow:none;
           box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
           -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;">
     <a href="index.html">ENTER</a>
</div>
```

how its done right now the link its working only for the text "ENTER"

Comment: the complete code http://pastebin.com/UBfy7EKW

Comment: @Erc <a href="your-link"><div>all contents here</div></a> but you can easily find its answer on google please do not ask this type of simple questions on SO which are already available on SO and on google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a href link for entire div in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465923/a-href-link-for-entire-div-in-html-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style it any way you like, but to make a div a link, here is a sample:

```
<div id="mylink" onclick="window.location.href='index.html';" style="padding:10px;border:1px solid black;max-width:100px;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">Enter</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the div with the a tag. Here is the HTML:
ENTER